# Can we Switch between process called by fork() C,like Switch player

Tags: c, switch-statement, fork, exec

for example i'm using fork to call 4 player.c as a child and want to create board game,and after each player finish the turn, program gonna pause that player.c and switch to another it's gonna repeat like this,until someone win the game

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be something some form of mutual exclusion might achieve. This question is fairly vague so my answer will also be more general rather than providing code

However firstly you must think about if multiprocessing is actually needed here.  The main reason for using multiple processes is so your progran can do multiple tasks **at the same time.**

It appears that in fact you simply wish to serialise a series of tasks. However as you appear to be fairly new (apologies if this assumption is wrong) I shall assume you still want to learn about multiprocessing even if it is not the best solution here.

Ok so there are two fundamental ways of looking at multiple processes in the most general sense, shared resources/objects and message passing.

Shared resources operate on having several processes given access to the same memory, file or some other thing at the same time. If you wish to go with this approach, assuming you are using a POSIX OS given the presence of fork you will want to look into the mmap or shared memory set of calls in POSIX as well as POSIX mutual exclusion or semaphore objects.

If however you wish to use message passing you might investigate POSIX message queues or even more simply UNIX sockets or pipes or even just writing and reading to a file.

I cannot advise you on which technique to use as the performance differences are complex and fairly subtle and beyond the scope of this answer. However I would look into both techniques and see what conceptually seems best to you.